# Incomplete HDFS URI, no host

Tags: csv, pyspark, hdfs

I am trying to read a csv file from HDFS through PySpark. 
I am using the following code:

```
path='hdfs://XX.XX.XX.XX:X000'

myrdd=sc.textFile(path)
```

The file can be read properly. However, later on when I am trying to convert it to a data frame I got the following error:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o423.partitions.
: java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs://XX.XX.XX.XX:X000

The code I am using to create a data frame is:

```
from pyspark import Row
instance=Row('feature1', 'feature2')
ins=myrdd.map(lambda r: instance(*r))
df = hc.createDataFrame(ins)
df.collect()
```

Just to mention that if I change a little bit the path to a file that does not actually exist, the fake file can still be read somehow, which makes me think there is something wrong with the real file but I am not completely sure.Could it be a matter of configuration?

Comment: Did you try giving the file name. It seems your URI is hostname and portname only. While you should give file path and generally hdfs path is like hdfs://nameservice1/path_to_file_dir

Answer (score 2):

In my in my instance I had to provide the full path i.e.

`val file = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/$username/input/file.csv")`